# How can I prevent the computation of fields during the installation of an Odoo module?

Tags: odoo

I have this situation:

- I want to install a module that inherits module `account` and adds a field in `account.move` and `account.move.line` models.
- I have more than 500k in records for that model
- Computation of the field is making installing the app to take lot of time.

I want to:

- Skip the computation for existing records at the first time so that I can decide when to do it.

Creating the field in DB before installing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the column on the DB, Odoo skips the computation for existing records.

Easy case: existing model and field is Char / Integer.

If the model already exists and the field is a char, then you only have to alter table and add the column as varchar or integer.

`alter table your_model add column your_field varchar;`

Complex case (many2one, many2many fields).

How to get the query for it?

- Install the dependencies of your module in a new database.

`odoo-bin -i your_module_dependencies -d new_db --init-db --stop-after-init`

- Install your module in the new database with log sql

`odoo-bin -i your_module -d new_db --log-level=debug_sql --logfile logfile.txt --stop-after-init`

- Then in logfile.txt you will have the queries needed for creating table and fields. Execute in your DB. Don't forget constraints, indexes and other needed stuff.

`2024-02-08 15:17:10,002 234036 DEBUG odoo5 odoo.sql_db: [3.057 ms] query:  CREATE TABLE "your_model_table"....`

- Install your module in your DB.

Comment: Could you add the Queries for the simple field types `char` and `integer`?